# which one is better for checking images? php or js

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, file-upload

I need to check images of contents on website.

I wrote code use php that doesn't have a problem, but I found some different ways on internet(Click to see [example](https://makitweb.com/check-broken-image-jquery-ajax/)!)

from your opinion which is more efficient?

My website template seems like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o60oU.jpg

below is my php code :

```
$random_img = rand(1,9); // I have saved images to folder img_1, img_2 ...                                  
$fixed_image = "<img src='public/img/duz/img_".$random_img.".jpg' style='width: 100%; height:320px; filter: blur(.1rem);' border:2px solid red;>";
$uploaded_img_file = "public/upload/$value->content_img";
$img_url = $value->content_img;                                 
$find_letters = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png','gif','svg');


$match = (str_replace($find_letters, '', substr($img_url,-4)) != substr($img_url,-4));
//true if the last 4 characters of img url match the 4 characters in the array; returns false if it does not match

if (empty($value->content_img)) {
            echo $fixed_img;
            echo $a;                                                
    }elseif (file_exists($uploaded_img_file)) {
        echo "<img src='".$uploaded_img_file."'>";
        //print_r($uploaded_img_file);
    }elseif (strlen($img_url)>=3) { //If the string length of the data from the database exceeds 3 characters. (no image if less than three characters)

        if (filter_var($img_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false && $match==true) { //url validation check

            echo "<img src='".$img_url."'>";
        }else{
            echo $fixed_img;
            $String_title = $value->content_title;
            $title_limit = limit_text($String_baslik, 10);
            echo $a;
        }
        //print_r($img_url);
    }else{
        echo $fixed_img;
        echo '<div style="position:absolute; left:15px; bottom:5px; text-decoration: none;"><span>Merhaba</span></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for alternative ways to do this, or is there an issue with your PHP code in your question?

Comment: php code is correct no problem with that but may be I can handle this problem with JS but I cant compute its efficiency

Comment: I'd advise staying with PHP, doing something like this in JavaScript adds more work for the browser to do, which depending on the number of images needed to be checked, could add unnecessary work, generating lag.

Comment: thank you very much @FluxCoder Now the PHP code works. As you said, changing it to JS may be unnecessary work.